# Difference between test strategy and test plan?

Tags: manual-testing, test-plan

As per lot of articles/google it is very hard to understand or explain the exact difference between test plan & strategy. Recently have gone through one of the interview and seems my answer didn't convince to the interviewer.
So if anyone can help me in answering this to understand the ***thin line between Test plan & strategy*** please. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better asked on https://sqa.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on sqa stack exchange site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the difference attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go by the word. Test Plan means we are planning for particular scope. We have to test on given environment withing given time frame defined in Test Plan. While the strategies will be common at organization level which is high level description about testing, what kind of testing and where etc.

Answer (score 1):

Difference between Test Strategy and Test Plan is as follow:

**Test Strategy** is written at a high-level mostly by QA Manager which defines the approach of testing. Test Strategy is derived from the Business Requirement Document, it basically sets the standards for testing.
Test Strategy contains the following:

- Scope
- Business Challenges
- Testing approaches
- Test deliverables
- Bug tracking approaches
- Automation
- Risks

**Test Plan** is written by Senior/Lead QA which includes details related to testing i.e. how to test, features to be tested, types of testing. Test Plan is derived from SRS.
Test Plan contains the following:

- Objective
- Test Environments
- Features In/Out Scope
- Entry/Exit Criteria
- Types of testing
- Status

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a Test Strategy is developed by the project manager to define an overall approach to test an application. It outlines what is needed to achieve defined testing objectives. You can have a separate test strategy for manual and [automated testing](https://medium.com/@vlad.ershov/how-to-build-a-test-automation-strategy-aa0426e38991)to specify factors such as the scope of what needs to be tested, which tools will be used, what standards will be followed, and how bug tracking will be reported.

There are usually multiple Test Plans that focus on different areas and features of the application to detail the functionality that will be tested, a step-by-step plan of how it will be tested and what acceptance criteria must be met that will pass/fail the viability of the implementation. It should include a timeline of when testing must start and finish, who will be responsible, as well as the detail of the testing environment.